# Using Supervisor to run ratchet websockets and queue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I have made an artisan command to run a websockets on some port like below

```
class webSockets extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'run:socket {port?}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Run websockets for specified port';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(RedisInterface $redis)
    {
        $this->redis=$redis;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
       $port = $this->argument('port');
       if($port=='8182') {
            $server = IoServer::factory(
                         new SocketController($this->redis),$port
                    );
       }
       else if($port=='8181'){
            $server = IoServer::factory(
                         new Socket1Controller($this->redis),$port
                    );
       }



       $server->run();
    }
}
```

I can run those sockets easily running an artisan command like below

```
php artisan run:socket 8181
php artisan run :socket 8182
```

I need to deploy it on a production server where thousand of devices are connected on that web sockets . **I tried supervisor to daemonize the process but no luck**

My conf file looks like below

```
[program:ratchet]
command                 = php /var/www/v3 artisan run:socket 8181;php /var/www/v3 artisan run:socket 8182
process_name            = Ratchet
numprocs                = 1
autostart               = true
autorestart             = true
stdout_logfile          = ./logs/info.log
stderr_logfile          = ./logs/error.log
```

I realised both port 8181 and 8182 are free and are not receiving any messages.

When I tried `sudo service supervisorctl` I saw all process have uptime 0:00:00 and different pids

```
laravel_queue                    RUNNING   pid 62246, uptime 0:00:00
ratchet:Ratchet                  RUNNING   pid 62245, uptime 0:00:00
supervisor> status
laravel_queue                    RUNNING   pid 62305, uptime 0:00:00
ratchet:Ratchet                  RUNNING   pid 62304, uptime 0:00:00
supervisor> status
laravel_queue                    RUNNING   pid 62419, uptime 0:00:00
ratchet:Ratchet                  RUNNING   pid 62418, uptime 0:00:00
supervisor> status
laravel_queue                    RUNNING   pid 62553, uptime 0:00:00
ratchet:Ratchet                  RUNNING   pid 62552, uptime 0:00:00
supervisor> status
laravel_queue                    RUNNING   pid 62689, uptime 0:00:00
ratchet:Ratchet                  RUNNING   pid 62688, uptime 0:00:00
supervisor> status
laravel_queue                    RUNNING   pid 62819, uptime 0:00:00
ratchet:Ratchet                  RUNNING   pid 62818, uptime 0:00:00
supervisor> status
```

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I managed to fix it by making seperate process on supervisor

1. Manage queue

**In /etc/supervisord/conf.d/ create laravel_queue.conf:**

```
[program:laravel_queue]
command= php artisan queue:listen redis --timeout=7200
directory=/var/www/gpsv3
stderr_logfile=/var/www/gpsv3/storage/logs/laraqueue.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/gpsv3/storage/logs/laraqueue.out.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

**Give it execute permissions: chmod +x laravel_queue.conf**

Now update Supervisor with: sudo supervisorctl reread. And start using those changes with: sudo supervisorctl update.

2. socket Listener

**In /etc/supervisord/conf.d/ create socket.conf:**

```
[program:socket]
command= php artisan run:socket 8182
directory=/var/www/gpsv3
stderr_logfile=/var/www/gpsv3/storage/logs/socket.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/gpsv3/storage/logs/socket.out.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

**Give it execute permissions: chmod +x socket.conf**

Now update Supervisor with: sudo supervisorctl reread. And start using those changes with: sudo supervisorctl update.